# Why won't `emacs -nw -f org-mode foo` open `foo` in `org-mode`?

Tags: major-mode, command-line-arguments

I want to open a file `foo` in `org-mode` on the terminal. However, Issuing `emacs -nw -f org-mode foo` opens `foo` in `Fundamental` mode. What's wrong with my command?

Comment: I bet your scratch buffer is in org-mode, though. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to do it by switching the order around

```
emacs -nw foo -f org-mode
```

After reading the help, if the function is a command, it is just like pressing a key command to do it.  There's also the `--file` option and `--find-file` option, so I figured it is executing `find-file` when you put the filename on the command line, and would call these in order.  So potentially it could be:

```
emacs -nw --find-file foo --funcall org-mode
```

Comment: The second command doesn't work for me but the first does. Thanks!

Comment: just fixed the second command